# How to increase java memory in openfire

Tags: java, openfire

i have Openfire 3.6.3 installed on my linux server . When i log into the openfire admin panel, Java Memory is showing 62.98 MB of 63.31 MB (99.5%) used . How can i increase the java memory?. Please guide me

Answer (score 4):

Add a line like this in /etc/sysconfig/openfire

OPENFIRE_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx512m"

(Reference: [site](http://www.igniterealtime.org/community/thread/27552))

Answer (score 4):

Change this value:

```
#OPENFIRE_OPTS="-Xmx1024m"
```

to

```
OPENFIRE_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx2048m"
```

In this location (CentOS/Linux):

```
vi /etc/sysconfig/openfire
```

Answer (score 1):

Find the command that starts Java and add this command line parameter: `-Xmx<size>`

For example, use `-Xmx128m` to let Java use 128 MB of memory. The full command might be something like `/path/to/java -Xmx128m -jar openfire.jar`